# Subtract following observations from the first of each level

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 24.341 obs of 6 variables, ordered first by Point.ID and then by Day, that looks like the following:

```
Point.ID    Day        E       N        Z
P1          2012-03-16 676620.5 4090699 26.82750
P1          2012-03-17 676620.5 4090699 26.82698
P1          2012-03-18 676620.5 4090699 26.82689
P10-Ref1    2012-03-16 676491.8 4090636 76.16396
P10-Ref1    2012-03-17 676491.8 4090636 76.16450
P10-Ref1    2012-03-18 676491.8 4090636 76.16519
P10-Ref1    2012-03-19 676491.8 4090636 76.16646
P11         2012-03-16 676496.7 4090619 75.77662
P11         2012-03-17 676496.7 4090619 75.77746
P11         2012-03-18 676496.7 4090619 75.77769
P11         2012-03-19 676496.7 4090619 75.77887
```

The number of E, N and Z observations are different per point, but the same within each other (E, N and Z).

I want to subtract the following observations from the first of the variables E, N and Z per each level of Point.ID variable and add the outcomes to the data.frame in a new variable.

I did the following, after a long time of research and attemptings with dplyr, ddply, etc., and when I plot the results it appears to work well, but I need a confirmation from an expert:

```
daily_means$E_disp <- ave(daily_means$E, daily_means$Point.ID,
                          FUN = function(x) x[1] - x)
daily_means$N_disp <- ave(daily_means$N, daily_means$Point.ID,
                          FUN = function(x) x[1] - x)
daily_means$Z_disp <- ave(daily_means$Z, daily_means$Point.ID,
                          FUN = function(x) x[1] - x)
```

Feel free to suggest a better solutions that I know it exists but I can't figure it out because of my short background.

Comment: Your `ave` code does what you describe (subtracting all values in each group from the first value of the group). I don't understand though the *_disp columns to your data frame. Shouldn't all those be 0?

Comment: They're the ave outcome. I shouldn't post with.

Comment: Only for `Z` I don't get all 0.

Comment: I'll edit the input.

Comment: You can loop to get it all at once, i.e. `sapply(df[3:5], function(i) with(df, ave(i, Point.ID, FUN = function(x)x[1] - x)))`

Comment: Much more clean! Thank you!